# Custom validation within DbContext.ValidateEntity throws ObjectDisposedException

Tags: entity-framework

I appreciate if you could help me understand why ObjectDisposedException is thrown when I remove the checking `lodging.DestinationId != 0` from `DbContext.ValidateLodging()`, given below.

The sample code given below is from Julie’s Programming Entity Framework – DbContext and it can be used to reproduce the exception.

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2012 with Entity Framework 6.0.2

**EDITED 7/1:** Included StackTrace of the ObjectDisposedException.

**DbContext implementation & test data**

```
namespace DataAccess
{

public class BagaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        var result = base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);

        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            ValidateLodging(result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void ValidateLodging(DbEntityValidationResult result)
    {
        var lodging = result.Entry.Entity as Lodging;

        // PROBLEM: Removing lodging.DestinationId != 0 causes ObjectDisposedException.
        if (lodging != null && lodging.DestinationId != 0)
        {
            if (Lodgings.Any(l => l.Name == lodging.Name &&
            l.DestinationId == lodging.DestinationId))
            {
                result.ValidationErrors.Add(
                new DbValidationError(
                "Lodging",
                "There is already a lodging named " + lodging.Name +
                " at this destination.")
                );
            }
        }
    }

    public BagaContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BagaContext>(new InitializeBagaDatabaseWithSeedData());
    }
}



public class InitializeBagaDatabaseWithSeedData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BagaContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BagaContext context)
        {
            context.Destinations.Add(new Destination
            {
                Name = "Grand Canyon",
                Lodgings = new List<Lodging>
                    {
                        new Lodging {Name = "Grand Hotel"},
                        new Lodging {Name = "Dave's Dump"}
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

}

**Code to test DbContext.ValidateEntity implementation**

```
namespace Client
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateDuplicateLodging();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CreateDuplicateLodging()
    {
        using (var context = new BagaContext())
        {
            var destination = context.Destinations.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "Grand Canyon");
            try
            {
                context.Lodgings.Add(new Lodging
                {
                    Destination = destination,
                    Name = "Grand Hotel"
                });
                context.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Save Successful");
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Save Failed: ");
                foreach (var error in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                    string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                    error.ValidationErrors.Select(v => v.ErrorMessage)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Model classes**

```
namespace Model
{
[Table("Locations", Schema = "baga")]
public class Destination
{
    public Destination()
    {
        this.Lodgings = new List<Lodging>();
    }

    [Column("LocationID")]
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    [Required, Column("LocationName")]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
}

public class Lodging
{
    public int LodgingId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [MinLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column("destination_id")]
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public Destination Destination { get; set; }
}
```

}

**StackTrace of the ObjectDisposedException**

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.get_Connection()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
at DataAccess.BagaContext.ValidateLodging(DbEntityValidationResult result) in c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Learning\EF\StackOverflowQuestions\DataAccess\BreakAwayContext.cs:line 38
at DataAccess.BagaContext.ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary`2 items) in c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Learning\EF\StackOverflowQuestions\DataAccess\BreakAwayContext.cs:line 26
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at Client.Program.CreateDuplicateLodging() in c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Learning\EF\StackOverflowQuestions\Client\Program.cs:line 34
at Client.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Learning\EF\StackOverflowQuestions\Client\Program.cs:line 18
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace of the ObjectDisposedException?

Comment: @SteveRuble: StackTrace added. Thanks.

Comment: `lodging.DestinationId != 0` is a red herring (DestinationId will always be 0, because you've only set `lodging.Destination` and the `Lodging` instance is not proxied (i.e., you created it with `new` so it's a POCO that doesn't have logic for setting `DestinationId` when the `Destination` property is set)). You should check `lodging.Destination != null` instead. This doesn't explain the exception, though. I'm still trying to figure that out (I think it has something to do with issuing a query from inside the validation system).

Comment: Just as an experiment, can you add `context.Lodgings.FirstOrDefault();` right inside the using statement in the `CreateDuplicateLodging`? (The idea is to force a query in the Lodgings DbSet before validation is run.) Does the same exception still get thrown?

Comment: @SteveRuble (1) Setting Lodging.DestinationId = Destination.DestinatinId still throws the ObjectDisposedException and I had already tried this. (2) Included context.Lodgings.FirstOrDefault(); inside the using statement and now the ObjectDisposedException is thrown right at this new statement.

Comment: @SteveRuble I'm not sure if your comment about lodging.DestinationId being always 0 and having to check lodging.Destination != null is correct because DbContext calls ChangeTracker.DetecChanges() before it calls DbContext.ValidateEntity() hence relationships have been already fixed up when you get to ValidateEntity(). To my knowledge lodging.DestinationId != 0 is not really required here but by removing it causes the Exception to be thrown.

Comment: I don't think DetectChanges is called until after validation, but in any case the fact that `context.Lodgings.FirstOrDefault()` causes an exception to be thrown makes me think there's something wrong with that table. Are you able to successfully make any queries against the Lodgings DbSet?

Comment: @SteveRuble (1) ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() - Based on what I've read and tested this is called before validation takes place. I can see lodging.DestinationId already correctly updated when DbContext.ValidateEntity() starts. (2) Lodgings table - I can query this table without issues and in fact have recreated the database but the exception keeps occurring. However if I moved context.Lodgings.FirstOrDefaul() before querying Destinations, then no exceptions till DbContext.ValidaeEntity is run.

Comment: I found some time to create a repro project, and learned that the relationship fixup is done in the `Lodgings.Add()` method, which I didn't know. Unfortunately, I experienced no ObjectDisposedExceptions, the validation worked correctly. Is there anything else interesting about your situation which isn't in the question?

Comment: @SteveRuble Thanks. To simulate the exception you have to remove lodging.DestinationId != null in ValidateLodging(). I assume you did this change prior to testing the code. I have given all the info I could think of above: full source code, test data, my dev environment etc... I can reproduce this exception and did so in two different computers. Pls let me know if you did the change I have mentioned above. Thanks for your support in this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a somewhat hacky solution, but I don't know exactly what the problem is. Luckily, this is probably a testing-induced error, since you're probably not planning on using DropCreateDatabaseAlways outside of a testing context.

The problem goes away if you don't execute any queries *during the seeding process*. One way to do this is to prevent validation until the SaveChanges has completed at least once in the app domain (SaveChanges is called during seeding.) A (possibly over) simple way to do this would be to modify `BagaContext` as follows:

```
private static bool _seedingComplete;
public override int SaveChanges()
{
   var result = base.SaveChanges();
   _seedingComplete = true;
   return result;
}

protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
{
   var result = base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);

   if (_seedingComplete && result.IsValid)
   {
      ValidateLodging(result);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Again, I don't know exactly why executing a query during seeding causes this issue, but if you can figure out a way to avoid that you should be OK.

**Edit to add more explanation:**

The reason that the clause `lodging.DestinationId != 0` in the if statement in `ValidateLodging` has the effect of preventing the error is that during seeding *all* Destination records will have an ID of 0, because they haven't been inserted yet. Because DestinationId will always be 0 during seeding, this clause prevents the `Lodgings.Any(...)` query from being executed.

One reason this issue was so hard for me to figure is that the `Lodgings.Any(...)` query during seeding *doesn't* cause the exception to be thrown, but it *does* break the `Lodgings` DbSet so that it can't be used for real queries later on. It took me a while to figure out where the DbSet was getting broken.

Comment: @SteveRubble: First of all thanks very much for looking into this. As you said, this looks like an error induced by the seeding process. I thought it's alright to let EF recreate the DB (for testing purposes) within the same using block. ie. This error can be avoided by recreating the DB within a different using block prior to executing the above client code. But I still don't understand how checking for lodging.DestinationId != 0 prevents this exception. I will look into this further and will post if I find anything interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @RanC, good call - creating and disposing another DbContext is probably a better solution than trying to track the seeding state inside the context.